# How to obtain selected UV pairs on same edge in Python?

Tags: python, scripting, uv, uv-image-editor, bmesh

I have a problem about Python scripting in Blender.
I want to get selected UV pairs on same edge and write below code.

[image: UV Pair]

```py
obj = context.active_object
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv.verify()
sel_faces = [f for f in bm.faces if f.select]

# get selected UV lists in UV/Image Editor
cand_loops = []
for f in sel_faces:
    for l in f.loops:
        if l[uv_layer].select:
            cand_loops.append(l)

# get UV pairs which two UVs on the edge are selected in UV/Image Editor
selected_uv_pairs = []
for l in cand_loops:
    le = l.edge
    # two UVs are selected (This if-statement **DOES NOT** work correctly)
    if le.link_loops[0][uv_layer].select and le.link_loops[1][uv_layer].select:
        selected_uv_pairs.append(le)
```

But above code does not work correctly.
Please tell me the idea to obtain selected UV pairs on same edge.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. I've taken the liberty to remove the construction of unnecessary lists, and used generators in their place.

The most important change is indeed in that `if` statement. Instead of using the `link_loops` list (which can be of arbitrary length), it's better to only use `link_loop_next`. Since you loop over all selected edges anyway, it's enough to look at the 'next' edge only.

```
import bpy, bmesh

obj = bpy.context.active_object
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv.verify()
sel_faces = (f for f in bm.faces if f.select)

def find_loops():
    """Generator, yields loops of selected mesh faces"""

    for f in sel_faces:
        for l in f.loops:
            yield l

def find_selected_loops():
    """Generator, yields loops that are selected in UV editor"""

    for l in find_loops():
        if l[uv_layer].select and l.link_loop_next[uv_layer].select:
            yield l

# Show the coordinates of selected loops. Note that loops are printed
# twice, once for the (A -> B) edge, and once for the (B -> A) edge.
print()
for l in find_selected_loops():
    print(l.vert.co, ' -> ', l.link_loop_next.vert.co)
```

If you want to remove the distinction between `(A -> B)` and `(B -> A)` loops, you could extend the `find_selected_loops()` generator so that it stores the tuples `(l.vert, l.link_loop_next.vert)` in a set, and only `yield` those edges whose `(l.link_loop_next.vert, l.vert)` are not in that set.

Comment: Since unselected faces won't be shown in the UV editor, I think this approach is quite nice.

Comment: Thank you. I could achieve the purpose by your solution. And it's helpful about your suggestion about code improvement.