# How to obtain sequence of selected UV in Python?

Tags: python, uv, uv-image-editor, bmesh

Sorry for continuous post from below post.
This question is related to it.

[How to obtain selected UV pairs on same edge in Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95824/how-to-obtain-selected-uv-pairs-on-same-edge-in-python)

I want to obtain sequence of selected UV in Python.
But I did not come up with the implementation.

[image]

I show you my trial code.
This code **DOES NOT** work correctly. (only 2 loops can be obtained)

```python
obj = context.active_object
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv.verify()
sel_faces = [f for f in bm.faces if f.select]

for f in sel_faces:
    for l in f.loops:
        if l[uv_layer].select:
            first_loop = l
            break

loop_seq = [first_loop]
loop = first_loop
while True:
    if loop[uv_layer].select and loop.link_loop_next[uv_layer].select:
        loop_seq.append(loop.link_loop_next)
        loop = loop.link_loop_next
    else:
        break
```

Is there any mistake above codes?

Comment: The code is incomplete (`first_loop` is undefined), so it's unclear where it comes from, and thus we can't fully understand your code.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to paste code. i edited

Comment: The code won't work because it is looping over faces, and then over the edges of that face. As a result, sequential loops won't be seen in a sequential manner. `link_loop_next` always points to the next loop of the same face. I would construct a set of `(vertex1, vertex2)` tuples of selected UV loops, and then parse those to obtain sequences of `(vertex1, vertex2), (vertex2, vertex3), …` tuples.

Comment: Thanks. i think we don't have any solution to realize that without your solution.